# How to get results in OPENJSON from whole json?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, nested

I have a JSON structure which has several elements with their respective values.
Each element has method.mash_temp, ingredients.malt and ingredients.hops, all of which can has multiple values.
How would I query it so I get values from each element? (there's 25 elements, in this example is only 2 for simplification)

I use sql server 2019
P.S. I'm not even sure if I'm using "elements" in te correct context, but I think you'll get what I'm trying to do

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '
 {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Buzz",
        "tagline": "A Real Bitter Experience.",
        "first_brewed": "09/2007",
        "description": "A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.",
        "image_url": "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png",
        "abv": 4.5,
        "ibu": 60,
        "target_fg": 1010,
        "target_og": 1044,
        "ebc": 20,
        "srm": 10,
        "ph": 4.4,
        "attenuation_level": 75,
        "volume": {
            "value": 20,
            "unit": "litres"
        },
        "boil_volume": {
            "value": 25,
            "unit": "litres"
        },
        "method": {
            "mash_temp": [
                {
                    "temp": {
                        "value": 64,
                        "unit": "celsius"
                    },
                    "duration": 75
                }
            ],
            "fermentation": {
                "temp": {
                    "value": 19,
                    "unit": "celsius"
                }
            },
            "twist": null
        },
        "ingredients": {
            "malt": [
                {
                    "name": "Maris Otter Extra Pale",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 3.3,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Caramalt",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.2,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Munich",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.4,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "hops": [
                {
                    "name": "Fuggles",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 25,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "start",
                    "attribute": "bitter"
                },
                {
                    "name": "First Gold",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 25,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "start",
                    "attribute": "bitter"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Fuggles",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 37.5,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "middle",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                },
                {
                    "name": "First Gold",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 37.5,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "middle",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cascade",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 37.5,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "end",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                }
            ],
         }
},
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Trashy Blonde",
        "tagline": "You Know You Shouldnt",
        "first_brewed": "04/2008",
        "description": "A titillating, neurotic, peroxide punk of a Pale Ale. Combining attitude, style, substance, and a little bit of low self esteem for good measure; what would your mother say? The seductive lure of the sassy passion fruit hop proves too much to resist. All that is even before we get onto the fact that there are no additives, preservatives, pasteurization or strings attached. All wrapped up with the customary BrewDog bite and imaginative twist.",
        "image_url": "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/2.png",
        "abv": 4.1,
        "ibu": 41.5,
        "target_fg": 1010,
        "target_og": 1041.7,
        "ebc": 15,
        "srm": 15,
        "ph": 4.4,
        "attenuation_level": 76,
        "volume": {
            "value": 20,
            "unit": "litres"
        },
        "boil_volume": {
            "value": 25,
            "unit": "litres"
        },
        "method": {
            "mash_temp": [
                {
                    "temp": {
                        "value": 69,
                        "unit": "celsius"
                    },
                    "duration": null
                }
            ],
            "fermentation": {
                "temp": {
                    "value": 18,
                    "unit": "celsius"
                }
            },
            "twist": null
        },
        "ingredients": {
            "malt": [
                {
                    "name": "Maris Otter Extra Pale",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 3.25,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Caramalt",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.2,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Munich",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.4,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "hops": [
                {
                    "name": "Amarillo",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 13.8,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "start",
                    "attribute": "bitter"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Simcoe",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 13.8,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "start",
                    "attribute": "bitter"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Amarillo",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 26.3,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "end",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Motueka",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 18.8,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "end",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                }
            ],
            "yeast": "Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™"
        },
        "food_pairing": [
            "Fresh crab with lemon",
            "Garlic butter dipping sauce",
            "Goats cheese salad",
            "Creamy lemon bar doused in powdered sugar"
        ],
        "brewers_tips": "Be careful not to collect too much wort from the mash. Once the sugars are all washed out there are some very unpleasant grainy tasting compounds that can be extracted into the wort.",
        "contributed_by": "Sam Mason <samjbmason>"
}';
```

Here's a query for ingredients.malt which works, but only gets data from the first element, how would I query it so I get all data?

```
SELECT name, amount_value, amount_unit 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.ingredients.malt')
WITH (  
    name nvarchar(30) '$.name'
    , amount nvarchar(max) '$.amount' as JSON
)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(amount, '$')
WITH (
  amount_value varchar(5) '$.value'
  , amount_unit nvarchar(50) '$.unit'
)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Opening the JSON on a higher level than the path `$.ingredients.malt`, will return other categories besides `malt`.

You can use the [json_value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql) function to fetch values from a JSON string.

```
select  category.[key] as CategoryName,
        json_value(ingredient.[value], '$.name') as IngredientName,
        json_value(ingredient.[value], '$.amount.value') as IngredientAmount,
        json_value(ingredient.[value], '$.amount.unit') as IngredientUnit
from openjson(@json, '$.ingredients') category
cross apply openjson(category.[value], '$') ingredient
```

This gives me

```
CategoryName  IngredientName          IngredientAmount  IngredientUnit
------------  ----------------------  ----------------  --------------
malt          Maris Otter Extra Pale  3.3               kilograms
malt          Caramalt                0.2               kilograms
malt          Munich                  0.4               kilograms
hops          Fuggles                 25                grams
hops          First Gold              25                grams
hops          Fuggles                 37.5              grams
hops          First Gold              37.5              grams
hops          Cascade                 37.5              grams
```

---

To get the data from the second object in the JSON (`"id": 2`), the invalid JSON from the question must be corrected to be valid first. It is missing the square array brackets `[]`.

This turns the invalid JSON

```
{
  "id": 1,
  ...
},
{
  "id": 2,
  ...
}
```

into a valid JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    ...
  }
]
```

To parse the `malt` data from all objects, you can then use the query below:

```
select  json_value(item.[value], '$.name') as ItemName,
        json_value(ingredient.[value], '$.name') as MaltName,
        json_value(ingredient.[value], '$.amount.value') as MaltAmount,
        json_value(ingredient.[value], '$.amount.unit') as MaltUnit
from openjson(@json2, '$') item
cross apply openjson(item.[value], '$.ingredients.malt') ingredient;
```

Resulting in

```
ItemName       MaltName                MaltAmount  MaltUnit
-------------  ----------------------  ----------  ---------
Buzz           Maris Otter Extra Pale  3.3         kilograms
Buzz           Caramalt                0.2         kilograms
Buzz           Munich                  0.4         kilograms
Trashy Blonde  Maris Otter Extra Pale  3.25        kilograms
Trashy Blonde  Caramalt                0.2         kilograms
Trashy Blonde  Munich                  0.4         kilograms
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, would you know how would I fetch data for example for $.ingredients from the whole json? Currently I'm getting data from object which has  "id": 1 in it, but the query seems not to fetch data from "id": 2.

Comment: The example JSON from the question is invalid. It is supposed to be an array of 2 elements `[ { "id":1, ... }, { "id": 2, ... } ]`. The example is missing the outer array brackets `[ ]`. The SQL engine parses the largest part of the string that is a valid JSON, for the example that is only the first part `{ "id": 1, ...}`.

Comment: @SvenMarenković Answer updated to include a new query that handles the corrected JSON.